# Is it really worth using the WCF REST Service Application type in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-4.0, restful-url

In the past, I have created a "robust" WCF service that can accept a complex (consumption of the service in a project) or RESTful requests.

I'm creating a new service and wanted to ease the creation of the restful endpoints.  So I see the WCF Rest Service Application, which I'm trying out.

The problem now, is that if I wanted to use this service from another .Net application, I would now have to go through the process of writing the completed event parsing/de-serialization.

I think in trying to over-simply the initial process, I will complicate the consumption process.

Are there any simpler ways around this, and is it best to stick to the main WCF service type and simply decorate the service contract methods appropriately.